# How to use a loop to increase a scroll view size (swift3)

Tags: ios, for-loop, if-statement, button, swift3

Right now every time the button is pressed a the score goes up. Once the score hits 3 the scrollviews height is increased. How can I make this so every time the button is pressed the height increases by 50 for a infinite amount of times.

```
@IBAction func enterScore(_ sender: Any) {
        score += 1


            THESCROOL.contentSize.height = 1000
            if score >= 3 {
                THESCROOL.contentSize.height = 5000

            }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i fully understand your question. Do you want to do something like this?

```
@IBAction func enterScore(_ sender: Any) {
    score += 1

    // every time the button is pressed, the contentHeight is increased by 50
    THESCROOL.contentSize.height = THESCROOL.contentSize.height + 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand your question too, but only to complement @bughana answer

```
@IBAction func enterScore(_ sender: Any) {
    //add score on button pressed
    score += 1    

    //just for every time the score is multiple of 3
    if 3 % 3 == 0
       //increase 50 with operator +=
       THESCROOL.contentSize.height += 50    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a global variable as counter set it as 0.

```
var counter = 0
```

then add this function to the button action

```
func btnTempClicked(sender:UIButton) -> Void {

    counter = counter+1
    let height = CGFloat(50*counter)

    scrlVw.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrlVw.frame.size.width, height: height)

}
```

NB: Content size is increased, not the frame height, so you will see the scrollview's scrolling area will increase.